# Getting "bonus is not defined" but everything else works in Python

Tags: python

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjZ3C.png)

```
"""
EmployeeBonus.py - This program calculates an employee's productivity bonus
"""

# Initialize variables here.
BONUS_1 = 50.00
BONUS_2 = 75.00
BONUS_3 = 100.00
BONUS_4 = 200.00

employeeName = input("Enter employee's name: ")
shiftString = input("Enter number of shifts: ")
transactString = input("Enter number of transactions: ") 
dollarString = input("Enter transactions dollar value: ")

numShifts = float(shiftString)
numTransactions = float(transactString)
dollarValue = float(dollarString)
# Write your code here
ProductivityScore = (dollarValue/numTransactions)/numShifts 
if ProductivityScore >= 200.00:
    bonus = BONUS_4
elif ProductivityScore >= 70 and ProductivityScore <= 199: 
    bonus = BONUS_3
elif ProductivityScore >= 31 and ProductivityScore <= 69: 
    bonus = BONUS_2
elif ProductivityScore >= 50:
    bonus = BONUS_1

# Output.
print("Employee Name: " + employeeName) 
print("Employee Bonus: $" + str(bonus))
```

Output

```
Enter employees name: Kim Smith 
Enter number of shifts: 25
Enter number of transactions: 75
Enter transactions dollar value: 40000
Employee Name: Kim Smith
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sandbox/EmployeeBonus.py", 
 line 32, in <module>
8))
    print("Employee Bonus: $" + str(bonus))
NameError: name 'bonus' is not defined
```

Trying to complete assignment on Cengage, and it is saying bonus is not defined in Python.

I tried to redefine bonus but I"m a student so not sure what to do. I have tried multiple fixes bur none work. As a student I really am not sure what to do.

Comment: please dont post pictures of code .... you probably just need `else: bonus = 0`

Comment: Your if ranges overlap 32 to 69 and greater 50, which value should used for e.g.51 ? Should >50 not be <31?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have a 'ProductivityScore' of 21.3 for the input values you use which does not fall into any of your criteria. This means the variable` 'bonus' never gets a value and remains undefined.  Maybe the line `elif ProductivityScore >= 50:` should actually be `elif ProductivityScore <= 30:`  given it's out of place anyway. Or otherwise you need to give 'bonus' a value so do as @Joran Beasley mentions in his comment or just simply initialise the variable 'bonus' with a value 0 (or whatever is appropriate as default) at the start of your code.

Comment: BTW a line like `elif ProductivityScore >= 70 and ProductivityScore <= 199:` can be simply written as `elif 70 <= ProductivityScore <= 199`

Answer (score -1):

You're getting the error because if none of the conditions in the `if` or `elif` statements are met, then no `bonus` variable is created. You can solve this in two ways:

1. Define a `bonus` variable outside the `if` and `elif` statements. Modified code:

```
numShifts = float(shiftString)
numTransactions = float(transactString)
dollarValue = float(dollarString)

bonus = 0 #Define the bonus variable

# Write your code here
Productivity Score = (dollarValue/numTransactions)/numShifts 
if ProductivityScore >= 200.00:
    bonus = BONUS_4
elif ProductivityScore >= 70 and ProductivityScore <= 199: 
    bonus = BONUS_3
elif ProductivityScore >= 31 and ProductivityScore <= 69: 
    bonus = BONUS_2
elif ProductivityScore >= 50:
    bonus = BONUS_1

# Output.
print("Employee Name: " + employeeName) 
print("Employee Bonus: $" + str(bonus))
```

2. Add an `else` statement so that if no condition is met, the `else` statement will be executed and the `bonus` variable gets created. Modified code:

```
numShifts = float(shiftString)
numTransactions = float(transactString)
dollarValue = float(dollarString)
# Write your code here
Productivity Score = (dollarValue/numTransactions)/numShifts 
if ProductivityScore >= 200.00:
    bonus = BONUS_4
elif ProductivityScore >= 70 and ProductivityScore <= 199: 
    bonus = BONUS_3
elif ProductivityScore >= 31 and ProductivityScore <= 69: 
    bonus = BONUS_2
elif ProductivityScore >= 50:
    bonus = BONUS_1
else:
    bonus = 0 #Set the bonus variable to zero if no condition is met

# Output.
print("Employee Name: " + employeeName) 
print("Employee Bonus: $" + str(bonus))
```